# How to add a bootstrap class to JHtml in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, bootstrap-sass, jhtmlarea

I am using following piece of code to display an image which I am fetching from    gravatar.com, so I want to use a bootstrap CSS class to make it more attractive. As soon as I add the style rather than showing the image it shows me the link to the image, when I redirect to the link I am able to see the image. Why I am getting this?

```
$html[] = JHtml::_('image', $grav_url,'class="img-circle"', JText::_('PLG_CONTENT_AVATAR'), null, true)
```

Here `$grav_url` is the url I am getting for the image and `img-circle` is the bootstrap class that I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the library you're using is here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/html/html.php#L567

So you can see in the parameter list that there is a param for `$attribs` which is of the type array. The other thing is there is an additional $alt param you have to pass which might be your jtext just out of order. To pass that to the method you would do:

```
$html[] = JHtml::_('image', $grav_url, JText::_('PLG_CONTENT_AVATAR'), array('class'=>'img-circle'), true)
```

Or you could build the array outside the method as a variable:

```
$attribs = array();
$attribs['class'] = 'img-circle'; // I think this should work? haven't tested though.

$html[] = JHtml::_('image', $grav_url, JText::_('PLG_CONTENT_AVATAR'), $attribs, true)
```