# Add class to PHP echo JHtml

Tags: php, html, image, class, joomla

I'm trying to add a class to the image below:

```
<?php 
   echo JHtml::_('image', 
                 $item->thumbnail,
                 $image_width, 
                 null, 
                 $this->escape($item->title)); 
?>
```

I tried the solution on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825763/how-to-add-a-bootstrap-class-to-jhtml-in-joomla) but it didn't work.

The result I'm trying to achieve is to add `class="scale"` to the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
JHtml::_('image', $item->thumbnail, escape($item->title), array('class'=>'scale', 'width'=> $image_width));
```

That should work.